# How do I get CSV files into an Estimator in Tensorflow 1.6

Tags: csv, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow (and my first question in StackOverflow)

As a learning tool, I am trying to do something simple.  (4 days later I am still confused)

I have one CSV file with 36 columns (3500 records) with 0s and 1s.
I am envisioning this file as a flattened 6x6 matrix.

I have another CSV file with 1 columnn of ground truth 0 or 1 (3500 records) which indicates if at least 4 of the 6 of elements in the 6x6 matrix's diagonal are 1's.

1. I am not sure I have processed the CSV files correctly.
2. I am confused as to how I create the features dictionary and Labels and how that fits into the DNNClassifier

I am using TensorFlow 1.6, Python 3.6

Below is the small amount of code I have so far.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

def x_map(line):
    rDefaults = [[] for cl in range(36)]
    x_row = tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=rDefaults)
    return x_row

def y_map(line):
    line = tf.string_to_number(line, out_type=tf.int32)
    y_row = tf.one_hot(line, depth=2)
    return y_row

x_path_file = os.path.join('D:', 'Diag', '6x6_train.csv')
y_path_file = os.path.join('D:', 'Diag', 'HasDiag_train.csv')

filenames = [x_path_file]
x_dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames)
x_dataset = x_dataset.map(x_map)
x_dataset = x_dataset.batch(1)
x_iter = x_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
x_next_el = x_iter.get_next()

filenames = [y_path_file]
y_dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames)
y_dataset = y_dataset.map(y_map)
y_dataset = y_dataset.batch(1)
y_iter = y_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
y_next_el = y_iter.get_next()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    x_el = (sess.run(x_next_el))
    y_el = (sess.run(y_next_el))
```

The output for `x_el` is:

`(array([1.], dtype=float32), array([1.], dtype=float32), array([1.], dtype=float32), array([1.], dtype=float32), array([1.], dtype=float32), array([0.] ...`  it goes on...

The output for y_el is:

```
[[1. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much there for a minimal working model. The main issue I see is that `tf.decode_csv` returns a tuple of tensors, where as I expect you want a single tensor with all values. Easy fix:

```
x_row = tf.stack(tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=rDefaults))
```

That should work... but it fails to take advantage of many of the awesome things the `tf.data.Dataset` API has to offer, like shuffling, parallel threading etc. For example, if you shuffle each dataset, those shuffling operations won't be consistent. This is because you've created two separate datasets and manipulated them independently. If you create them independently, zip them together then manipulate, those manipulations will be consistent.

Try something along these lines:

```
def get_inputs(
        count=None, shuffle=True, buffer_size=1000, batch_size=32,
        num_parallel_calls=8, x_paths=[x_path_file], y_paths=[y_path_file]):
    """
    Get x, y inputs.

    Args:
        count: number of epochs. None indicates infinite epochs.
        shuffle: whether or not to shuffle the dataset
        buffer_size: used in shuffle
        batch_size: size of batch. See outputs below
        num_parallel_calls: used in map. Note if > 1, intra-batch ordering
            will be shuffled
        x_paths: list of paths to x-value files.
        y_paths: list of paths to y-value files.

    Returns:
        x: (batch_size, 6, 6) tensor
        y: (batch_size, 2) tensor of 1-hot labels
    """

    def x_map(line):
        rDefaults = [[] for cl in range(n_dims**2)]
        x_row = tf.stack(tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=rDefaults))
        return x_row

    def y_map(line):
        line = tf.string_to_number(line, out_type=tf.int32)
        y_row = tf.one_hot(line, depth=2)
        return y_row

    def xy_map(x, y):
        return x_map(x), y_map(y)

    x_ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset(x_paths)
    y_ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset(y_paths)

    combined = tf.data.Dataset.zip((x_ds, y_ds))
    combined = combined.repeat(count=count)
    if shuffle:
        combined = combined.shuffle(buffer_size)
    combined = combined.map(xy_map, num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls)
    combined = combined.batch(batch_size)
    x, y = combined.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return x, y
```

To experiment/debug,

```
x, y = get_inputs()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    xv, yv = sess.run((x, y))

print(xv.shape, yv.shape)
```

For use in an estimator, pass the function itself.

```
estimator.train(get_inputs, max_steps=10000)

def get_eval_inputs():
    return get_inputs(
        count=1, shuffle=False
        x_paths=[x_eval_paths],
        y_paths=[y_eval_paths])

estimator.eval(get_eval_inputs)
```

Comment: Very helpful.  I am still confused as to how to create feature columns for a DNNClassifier.  I am assuming I will want to maintain the flat 36 column row ...

Comment: oh, sorry, read that as CNNClassifier, which I presumed was a convolutional NN. Just remove the reshape :). (edited)